# Folder create when user register joomla website?

Tags: module, joomla-user-groups, file-upload

In my Joomla site my users can upload and download files (docs and pdfs). So I want to create a separate folder for each and every user in my server. When a user register on my website a folder is create in the name of the user. If I delete a user the folder automatically should be deleted? Which file should I edit and how to write the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [write a small User Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla), you can use something like this to create the folder.

```
class PlgUserExample extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
    { 
        if($isnew) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a free module available at JED that can be configured to allow users to upload files to a folder with their username. Take a look at [Simple File Upload](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/8424). I've used it for one project, and it works fine, but at the end it depends on your specific requirements.

*From the description:*

> It includes the following key features:
>
> - Multiple modules on the same page with different settings
> - "Add Note" to uploaded files
> - Image re-size
> - Automated thumbnail creation for images
> - Image compress for JPEG and PNG
> - Now supports both "User Named Directory" and "User Defined Directory"! (see below)
> - CAPTCHA
> - List files in upload directory in pop-up (FancyBox)
> - Multiple files upload
> - Notification e-mail
> - And more...

Other similar extensions might be found at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management

Answer (score 2):

You can write a component and define `build` and `parse` methods (AKA `YOURCOMPONENTBuildRoute` and `YOURCOMPONENTParseRoute` functions) in your component's `router.php` instead of creating physical directories. Then, you need to create a menu with alias of `user` or `users` and link it to your component.